# Add field to query results in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I'm using this site https://data.epo.org/linked-data/sparql.html. I know these two queries work.

```
SELECT ?application ?appNum ?filingDate ?authority { 
?application rdf:type patent:Application ; 
patent:applicationNumber ?appNum ; 
patent:filingDate ?filingDate ; 
patent:applicationAuthority ?authority . 
FILTER (?filingDate >= "2022-01-01"^^xsd:date) 
} LIMIT 10


SELECT DISTINCT ?publication ?title ?abstract {
  ?publication text:query ( dcterms:abstract "vehicle" ) ;
      patent:titleOfInvention ?title ;
      dcterms:abstract        ?abstract ; 
      .
} LIMIT 10
```

However, when I add "patent:filingDate ?filingDate ;" to the second query, I fail to get results. The query that does not get results or gives an error is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?publication ?title ?abstract {
  ?publication text:query ( dcterms:abstract "vehicle" ) ;
      patent:titleOfInvention ?title ;
      dcterms:abstract        ?abstract ; 
      patent:filingDate ?filingDate ;
      .
} LIMIT 10
```

Do you know how to get the filingDate field in the second query? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: the date is not on the publication but on the application of the patent as you can see from any example, like https://data.epo.org/linked-data/data/publication/EP/2733687/A1/-

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT ?publication ?title ?abstract ?filingDate {
  ?publication text:query ( dcterms:abstract "vehicle" ) ;
      patent:titleOfInvention ?title ;
      dcterms:abstract        ?abstract ;
      patent:application ?app .
      ?app patent:filingDate ?filingDate .
} LIMIT 10`

Comment: for publication there would be the publicationDate of course, documentation of the ontology is here: https://data.epo.org/linked-data/documentation/patent-ontology-reference.html#application and https://data.epo.org/linked-data/documentation/patent-ontology-overview.html